# Derivation of the steepest direction

Tags: inequality, optimization, gradient-descent

The basic idea behind the derivation of the steepest direction is to find $\textbf{d}$ such that $f(\textbf{x}^{(k)} + \lambda \textbf{d})$ decreases the most for small values of $\lambda$

In other words, finding $\textbf{d} \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ that minimizes
$$
\frac{d}{d\lambda}f(\textbf{x}^{(k)} + \lambda \textbf{d})|_{\lambda = 0} = \langle \nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)}, \textbf{d})\rangle \qquad (1)
$$
Now using the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, we get
$$
|\langle\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)},\textbf{d} \rangle|^2 \leq \|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\|^2 \qquad (2) 
$$
with equality in case $\textbf{d}$ lies on the line spanned by $\nabla f(\textbf{x})^{(k)}$, so that
$$
\textbf{d} = -\frac{1}{\|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\|}\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)}) \qquad (3)
$$
delivers the steepest direction

Here are **my questions**:

- The Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality states that
  $$
  \boxed{| \textbf{u}^\top \textbf{v} | \leq \| \textbf{u}\| \|\textbf{v}\|}
  $$
  How can I get (2) with it?
- Now tackling the way we get to (3) we can start from (2)
  \begin{align*}
  |\langle\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)},\textbf{d} \rangle|^2 &\leq \|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\|^2
  \\
  ((\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})^\top\textbf{d})^2 &\leq \|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\|^2\\
  \end{align*}

But then again I'm stuck

**EDIT**
So by setting $\textbf{u} = \nabla f(x^{(k)}$ and $\textbf{v} = d$ with $\|\textbf{d}\| = 1$ as it is $\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, we can plug those 2 values into the CS inequality which gives

\begin{align*}
\langle \nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)}), \textbf{d} \rangle &\leq \|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\| \|\textbf{d}\|\\
\langle \nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)}), \textbf{d} \rangle &\leq \|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\| (1)\\
|\langle \nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)}), \textbf{d} \rangle|^2 &\leq \|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\|^2\\
\end{align*}
now setting
$$
\textbf{d} = -\frac{\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)}) }{\|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\|}
$$
We get
\begin{align*}
|\langle \nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)}), -\frac{\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)}) }{\|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\|} \rangle|^2 &\leq \|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\|^2\\
\frac{\|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\|^4}{\|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\|^2} &\leq \|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\|^2\\
\|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\|^2 &= \|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\|^2\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, take $\textbf{u}=\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})$ and $\textbf{v}=\textbf{d}.$ Then, just apply Cauchy-Schwarz and use that $\textbf{d}\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ (so, it has unit norm). To get the next equality, just plug that specific $\textbf{d}$ into the left-hand side of (2). This  maximizes the absolute value of the inner product, and making it negative, in turn, minimizes it (which is why we have a minus sign on $\textbf{d}$).

Comment: thanks for your answer @cmk. But $\textbf{d}$ is already in (2). How can I plug it again?

Comment: What I mean is that if you look at just the left-hand side of (2) and plug in the expression for $\mathbf{d}$ given in (3), then you'll get that the left and right of (2) are exactly equal. Since you already showed that the left is $\leq $ the right, this means you maximized the left. That is, the particular choice of $\textbf{d}$ in (3) maximizes the left-hand side of (2).

Comment: I added some more lines. Are those correct? maybe over complicated but I couldn't find easier. Why is there a minus sign in front of the $\textbf{d}$ in (3)

Comment: I would write the last line a bit differently (I'd just plug $\textbf{d}$ into the left, then show it equals exactly $\|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\|^2$), but what you wrote is still correct. What we now know is that the particular choice of $\textbf{d}$ makes the absolute value of your inner product maximized. But, its actual value (without absolute values) is $-\|\nabla f(\textbf{x}^{(k)})\|^2,$ which is negative, telling us that we've minimized the derivative.

Answer (score 2):

Teh derivation of (2) starts with the assumption (which the steps you presented did not state explicitly) that $\mathbf{d} = 1$.  With this added information, let $ u = \nabla f(\mathbf{x}^{(k)})$ and $v = \mathbf{d}$. Then CS says
$$
|u \cdot v|^2 \leq |v!^2 = |u|^2 (1) = ||\nabla f(\mathbf{x}^{(k)})||^2   
$$

From (2) you know that whatever direction is chosen for $\mathbf{d}$, the LHS is no greater than $||\nabla f(\mathbf{x}^{(k)})|||^2$.  Therefore if you can find a direction (a value of $\mathbf{d}$) such that equality holds, this is a direction (perhaps there could be others) maximizing the LHS.

$\nabla\mathbf{x}^{(k)}$ is one such value of $\mathbf{d}$ that give equality in (2).

Since the LHS gives the absolute value of the slope of the function along $\mathbf{d}$, to minimize the slope you need to choose $\mathbf{d}$ proportional to $\nabla\mathbf{x}^{(k)}$
but such that

- The magnitude of $\mathbf{d}$ is $1$, and
- $\nabla f(\mathbf{x}^{(k)})$ is negative.

Expression (3) is the unique expression having those properties.

Comment: I think you meant to write that $\|\textbf{d}\|=1.$

Comment: thank @cmk. I corrected it